# JSON Request for an UIImage from WordPress Post

Tags: json, swift, wordpress, api, request

I would like to download a picture of a json file online. This image should be displayed in a UIImageView.

At least I know that I need a JSON request but as I can bring the image in the ImageView I do not know

I've tried to download the image with a JSON request, but I have not managed it yet

My Code looks like this:

```
class HomeControllerTableView: UITableViewController{

    var coursesPicture = [CoursePicture]()
    var courseURL = [CourseURL]()

    // MARK: - CoursePicture
    struct CoursePicture: Codable {
        let links: LinksPICTURE

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case links = "_links"
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Links
    struct LinksPICTURE: Codable {
        let wpFeaturedmedia: [WpFeaturedmedia]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case wpFeaturedmedia = "wp:featuredmedia"
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WpFeaturedmedia
    struct WpFeaturedmedia: Codable {
        let href: String
    }


    struct CourseURL: Codable {
        let guid: GUIDURL
    }



    // MARK: - GUID
    struct GUIDURL: Codable {
        let rendered: String
    }

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var hello = ""
var hello2 = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView

        tableView.addSubview(imageView)

        fetchJSON()
        fetchJSONPicture()
        request()
        fetchJSONURL()



    }
public func fetchJSONPicture() {
        let urlString = "EXAMPLE_URL"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in

                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }

                do {

                    self.coursesPicture = [try JSONDecoder().decode(CoursePicture.self, from: data)]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)
                }

            }.resume()



    }

    public func fetchJSONURL() {
        let urlString = hello
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }

                do {

                    self.courseURL = [try JSONDecoder().decode(CourseURL.self, from: data)]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
        if let url = URL(string: hello2) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }

    }

    }
func request() {

        let coursePicture = coursesPicture[0]// Index out of Range error
        let courseUrl = courseURL[0] // Index out of Range error

        hello = coursePicture.links.wpFeaturedmedia[0].href 
        hello2 = courseUrl.guid.rendered
}
}
```

The JSON Request should bring me an URL from the JSON File and store it in a global variable. After that i use the global variable to get the URL from the Image.

The Picture that i would fetch is in a WordPress Post as contributing picture.

I would like to make this code as dynamic as possible but the problem is that i became an error that is called "Index out of range".

Can me help someone maybe?

Thanks

Comment: The error means that the array is empty in your case which most likely mean that either something went wrong when downloading or when decoding. Have you checked for any other errors being printed?

Comment: Yes thats the only error in the console. I was thinking that the DispatchQueue.main.async is the problem here because there are 3 functions for fetchingJSON but fetchJSONPicture must be the first one who finished because fetchJSONURL needs the data from fetchJSONPicture Request. Thats why i use var hello und var hello2 to store the information in one global variable to use them later in the fetchJSONURL

Comment: Well then you have an issue with asynchronous events so the crash occurs since the data hasn’t been downloaded yet.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I also tried to DispatchQueue.main.sync the events but this gives me again an index out of range. Maybe my structs are wrong too. I have tried it in many ways now and im very frustrated since one week.